# Telegram bot's host on the Vercel without templates

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, vercel

I wrote TG bot on Node.js and try to host it to the Vercel. In `localhost` my bot works without problems, but in the Vercel host it gives me `504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT`. Who know's how to fix it?

I tried to rework it with templates, but it's not effective for me. I want to host my project without templates of with `node-telegram-bot-api` on js.

It can be any other free host. I just need to host a small bot.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using Vercel with a **Hobby plan**, your telegram bot might be taking too long to be processed. So, after a few seconds, the bot responds with a **504: GATEWAY TIMEOUT error**.

To fix this, you need to reduce the amount of time your bot takes to process and respond or use the paid plan.